# Quick Numerical PNG Save

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, batch-processing, actions

I work with PNG frames when I make videos. So whenever I do it I usually save with .PSD, but the files got too big and I decided to switch to saving with .PNG

I was wondering if there is a way to make it so whenever I press a certain key it automatically saves my image with the next number up. 
EX: If I had 10 PNG images all labeled 1.png through 10.png and I hit a certain shortcut again then it'll save the next image as 11.png

Thanks, anything similar to this would be a great help also.

Comment: I don't know if there is a pre-made script that does just this... It would be relatively easy to make. That said this [photoshop file versions script of mine](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-file-versions-script) has all the necessary parts. It's main function is to save the document + save it again to adjacent folder as a separate file and it can now also save a jpeg or a png next to that file version. There's no setup where it only saves a png, though it would be an easy modification.

Comment: @Joonas Wow, thanks mate, that looks really useful. Just is there a way to change it from exporting in PSD and to PNG instead? Couldn't find that anywhere.

Comment: Well like I said in my previous comment, the purpose of the script is to save a psd file so there is no setup where it doesn't do that. In fact it sort of relies on it. I modified the script to only save png files: https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/0000973719e974421b684be874f58c9b — It will ask to save as psd file on first run if it's not already saved. This modification also relies to the psd file for the exports location.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you're using Photoshop of Illustrator, but on **Illustrator**:

1. I'd normally create an Artboard on each elements that I'd want to export as PNG. (Just use the Artboard tool and click the **grouped** elements you'd want to export.)
2. File > Export > Export As...
3. Rename the file
4. Set save as type (PNG)
5. Check the "Use Artboards" and select the number of Artboards you'd want to save or select All.
6. Export.

[image]

This method will automatically add a "-01" at the end of the file name and will increase the number for each artboard.

On **Photoshop** you could try the Image processor located on File > Scripts > Image Processor... Or create an action for exporting your frames (Window > Actions). Record your actions about exporting a frame with a specific name and save that action. Then play it on all your frames.